# Python Selenium-Debug a Simple Code with YouTube

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7LEWxX4AVI&list=PLPIqsJye1aPybIwQ1L47gY36lkQ6yL975&index=3&t=397s) for Selenium with Python:

So I did the same as the tutorial:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')

searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-input"]')
searchbox.send_keys('cooking')
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ANGUS/DATA_ANALYSIS/WEBSCRAPING/TextXXX.py", line 7, in <module>
    searchbox.send_keys('cooking')
  File "C:\Users\Angus\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\Angus\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Angus\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Angus\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you instead use the YouTube API?

Comment: add explicit wait for the element.

Comment: ....oh OK - so the webpage is not loading completely before next step (searchbox.send_keys('cooking'))....is implemented - hence the error?

Comment: Would you mind showing how to 'add an explicit wait for the element'?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that in order not to use the search is by inserting the query itself.

Code:

```
your_query = "cooking"

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + str(your_query))

time.sleep(5)
```

In this way, it is like you are going immediately in the output that you want after searching a specific query of yours. So, let's say that instead of typing cooking, you can .get() to the URL you want by adding your query into this URL.